# React Native Android app crashes on Facebook login/cancel

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk, upi

Environment:
OS: Windows 10
RN: 0.62.0
react-native-fbsdk: 2.0.0
Node: V11

Hi All,

I'm trying to integrate FB login to my android app through react-native-fbsdk. I followed the steps to integrate by creating the FB App "https://developers.facebook.com/apps/" and provided with necessary information. SHA1 hashkeys matches.
[image]

It was working well few days before and now it completely lost. It crashes my app on Login/Cancel login.

Login Button:

```
                        // loginBehaviorAndroid={'web_only'}
                        permissions={['email']}
                        onLoginFinished={(error: any, result: any) => {
                          if (error) {
                            console.log('login has error: ' +error);
                          } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                            console.log('login is cancelled.');
                          } else {
                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((myData: any) => {
                              console.log(`access token is ${JSON.stringify(myData)}`);
                              const accessToken = myData.accessToken.toString();
                              this.GetInformationFromToken(accessToken);
                            });
                          }
                        }}
                        onLogoutFinished={() => {
                          this.setState({myInformation: undefined})
                        }}
                      />
```

Login Handle:

```
GetInformationFromToken = async (accessToken: any) => {
    console.log('hi');
    const parameters = {
      fields: {
        string: 'id, name, first_name, last_name, middle_name, email, quotes',
      },
    };
    const myProfileRequest = new GraphRequest(
      '/me',
      {accessToken, parameters: parameters},
      async (error: any, myProfileInfoResult: any) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log('login info has error: ' + error);
        } else {
          console.log('result:', myProfileInfoResult);
          this.setState({myInformation: myProfileInfoResult});
          if (this.state.myInformation) {
            const json: any = await WPUserAPI.getUserByEmail(this.state.myInformation.email);

            if (json && json.code === undefined) {
              const usrLogin = await this.login(this.state.myInformation.email, this.state.myInformation.id);
              if (usrLogin && usrLogin.code !== undefined) {
                  LoginManager.logOut();
                  this.setState({myInformation: undefined})
                  return;
              }
            } else if (json && json.code !== undefined) {
              const result = await WPUserAPI.socialAccRegister(this.state.myInformation.name, this.state.myInformation.email, this.state.myInformation.first_name,
                this.state.myInformation.last_name, this.role[0].value, this.state.myInformation.id);
              if (result && result.code === 200) {
                const usrLogin = await this.login(this.state.myInformation.email, this.state.myInformation.id);
                if (usrLogin && usrLogin.code !== undefined) {
                  LoginManager.logOut();
                  this.setState({myInformation: undefined})
                  return;
                }
              } else {
                LoginManager.logOut();
                this.setState({myInformation: undefined})
                return;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    );
    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(myProfileRequest).start();
  };
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm stuck here since many days.

ADB.exe log from the device also attached.

```
AndroidRuntime: Process: com.v2farm, PID: 30816
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.v2farm/com.v2farm.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback.invoke(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5143)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5184)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback.invoke(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.upi.payment.UpiPaymentModule.onActivityResult(UpiPaymentModule.java:102)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.onActivityResult(ReactContext.java:288)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(ReactInstanceManager.java:738)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.ReactDelegate.onActivityResult(ReactDelegate.java:90)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate.onActivityResult(ReactActivityDelegate.java:112)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onActivityResult(ReactActivity.java:68)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.v2farm.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:24)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8292)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5136)
08-09 17:02:16.539 30816 30816 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 11 more
ActivityManager: crash : com.v2farm,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the mCallbackManager object is initialized in getPackages() with the following statement:

```
mCallbackManager = new CallbackManager.Factory().create();
```

Source: [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/faq/#faq_532433693628214)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, But it is already been initialized under MainApplication.java like this:

`private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
}
`

Comment: I figured this out. It is happening since I'm using another library for UPI payment transaction. It has a callback and been called everytime when FB login/logout (have no idea, why?).
For temporary, I commented only a part which was calling out during FB login and it is working fine. But not sure on how to get the fix without commenting it out.